# What's the best ratio for algebra tiles?

Tags: algebra, manipulatives

A good model for algebra are Algebra Tiles.

See: https://calculate.org.au/wp-content/uploads/sites/15/2019/03/lesson-sequence-for-algebra-tiles.pdf

In this presentation they recommend an aspect ratio of 3:14 for the "x" tile. This implicitly defines x = 4.666, though, of course x is a variable not a particular number! **Why do they recommend this?**

Another choice would be 1:10, though this could confuse algebra with place value.

Other numbers/ratios could be 2, 1.5, 2, 3 or even $\sqrt 2$ or $\phi$.

Answer (score 8):

They must have a mathematician on their team!  There is a very good reason to recommend $x=4.666$.

Consider a given length $x_0$.  We want to compare to $ax_0 $  to $b$ for $a,b \in \{1,2,3,...,10\}$.  The minimum difference $\textrm{min}(|ax_0 -b|)$ for $a,b \in \{1,2,3,..., 10\}$ will represent the "closest" one can make some number $ax_0$ to the number $b$ using some number of $x_0$ tiles and unit tiles (restricting yourself to between 1 and 10 of each type of tile).

Here is a graph of $f(x) = \textrm{min}(|ax -b|)$ for $a,b \in \{1,2,3,..., 10\}$:

[image]

[Desmos link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/aazy484fzp)

As you can see, $4.\bar{6}$ is one local maximum of this function, with an output of $\frac{1}{3}$.  This means that if you select a tile length of $x=4.\bar{6}$, the closest a student will be able to get any number of $x$ inch tiles and $1$ inch tiles is $\frac{1}{3}$ of an inch, which should be highly visible!

Answer (score 2):

The makers of algebra tiles don't want students concluding that x = 2 or 3.  To avoid that kinds of confusion is the reason that they don't have an integer ratio such as 1:2 or 1:3.

Futhermore when modeling a quadratic, the student will naturally, line up the tiles so that the x edges touch.  Imagine if the ratio was 1:3 and the student had 3x, the student could create an alternate model and leap to incorrect conclusions.

I don't know what advantages you see of having a ratio of $\sqrt 2$ or $\phi$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395938/why-is-varphi-called-the-most-irrational-number

Comment: So $\phi$ should have some advantage to being the "least misleading" number if you are modeling linear equations with integer equations.  Least likely to lead to coincidences of lengths matching up.

Comment: Of course, in practice, infinitely precise machining of parts is impossible, and even if it were the human eye cannot tell.  Still I wonder lengths close to the golden ratio avoid "mistaken identities" for small integer coefficients.  Might play with some simulations later.